# setting values inside jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my function i am declaring `bar='0'` i just want to update the value of bar='1' only if change is clicked, else the bar should have the default value as 0. so that when ever i alert the bar should alert.

i.e.,

If i  click on the change the bar should have the value of 1 else it should have the default value as 0

How can i do this ..

Here is the code i have tried so far

```
<script>
$(function(){
      var bar = "0";
      $('#change').click(function()
      {
      var bar = "1";
      });
      $('#fire').click(function()
      alert(bar);
      }
});
</script>
```

Comment: is 'change' an id or a class? the same question goes to 'action'. and can you provide your html markup.

Comment: i have updated it's change and fire `id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second time around, in the click handler, you shouldn't use var, as that would redeclare `bar` within the function scope of the click handler.

Simply remove the `var` as such:

```
$(function(){
  var bar = "0";
  $('change').click(function()
  {
    bar = "1"; // Remove `var`
  });
  $('action').click(function(){
    alert(bar);
  }
});
```

This is thanks to javascript's support for closures. I really recommend reading the closure bit (and rest) of Eloquent Javascript, available here: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Comment: Glad to help. Give that page a read if you have time – you'll enjoy javascript more by doing it!

Comment: sure do :) i will do it now itself